# Gawk not filtering out larger number?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, gawk

My simple gawk filter used in my program is not filtering out a value that is a digit longer than the rest.

Here is my text file:

```
172 East Fourth Street      Toronto     4   1890    1500000     6
2213 Mt. Vernon Avenue      Vaughn      2   890     500000      4
One Lincoln Plaza           Toronto     2   980     900000      1
```

The columns are separated by tabs.

My gawk script:

```
echo "Enter max price"
read price 

gawk -F "\t+" '$5 <= "'$price'"' file
```

The 1500000 value appears if I enter a value of 150001 or greater. I think it has to do with the gawk not reading the last digit correctly. I'm not permitted to change the original text file and I need to use the gawk command. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: use `-v` parameter to make use of shell variables in awk

Comment: @AvinashRaj how and where would I use the `-v` parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **`awk` command performs *lexical* comparison** rather than numerical comparison, because **the RHS - the price value - is enclosed in *double-quotes***.

Removing the double-quotes would help, but it's advisable to reformulate the command as follows:

```
 gawk -F '\t+' -v price="$price" '$5 <= price' file
```

The *shell* variable `$price` is now passed to Awk using `-v`, as *Awk* variable `price`, which is the safe way to pass values to `awk` - you can then use a *single*-quoted `awk` script without having to splice in shell variables or having to worry about which parts may be expanded by the shell up front.

*Afterthought*: As Ed Morton points out in a comment, **to *ensure* that a field or variable is treated as a *number*, append `+0` to it**; e.g., `$5 <= price+0` (conversely, append `""` to force treatment as a *string*).
By default, Awk *infers* from the values involved and the context whether to interpret a given value as a string or a number - which may not always give the desired result.

Comment: Thanks but I need it to work with multiple tabs, in my full script I pipe the gawk with other gawks to filter the 3rd 4th and 6th columns as well. They all work in my full program but just the 1500000 price keeps slipping through my filter for some reason.

Comment: @JoshTree: OK, I've gone back to `\t+` to avoid creating a distraction. Try it now - not having the double-quotes in there should properly perform _numerical_ comparison.

Comment: `gawk -F "\t+" '$2 == "'$city'"' listing | gawk -F "\t+" '$3 >= "'$bedrooms'"' | gawk -F "\t+" '$4 >= "'$space'"' | gawk -F "\t+" '$5 <= "'$price'"' | gawk -F "\t+" '$6 <= "'$weeks'"' | tr -s '\t' | sort -t $'\t' $sortby $ordering | column -s $'\t' -t` I actually use this to filter and sort and it works except the 1.5 Million value.

Comment: @JoshTree: My pleasure; glad to hear it.

Comment: Note that awk could STILL decide to do a string comparison instead of numeric given the above code as the type of every variable is "numeric string" and so awk has to guess whether you want it to be treated as a string or a number based on context and content. The way to make SURE that awk uses a numeric comparison is to write it as `$5 <= price+0` (and to force a string comparison would be `$5 <= price""`).

Comment: JoshTree Wherever you learned to use `"'$price"'`, etc. - never use that source again as it's completely wrong about that and so almost certainly wrong about other fundamentals. Also chaining awks with pipes like in your comment is completely the wrong approach (see the answer/comment from @glennjackman - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34100513/1745001). Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins so you can learn some awk fundamentals - it'll make your scripting life a whole lot easier.

Comment: @EdMorton: Good point re forcing to a number / string, thanks; I've updated the answer.

Comment: @EdMorton Haha thats the way our professor showed us how to do the variables in gawk so I assumed it was right. But the piped gawks were my idea as he never showed us how to do multiple filters. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Your professors an idiot, get a new one :-). Seriously though - never do that as it makes the shell variables expand to become part of the actual awk command and as such can cause you ALL sorts of weird and wonderful problems given various contents of the shell variables. You CAN make it a bit more robust with `awk '{... "'"$shellvar"'" ...}'` but just don't do it at all - use `-v awkvar="$shellvar"` unless you need some specific functionality of `awk 'script' "$shellvar"` or `awk 'script' awkvar="$shellvar"`.

Answer (score 2):

You're really calling a separate gawk for each column? One will do:

```
gawk -F "\t+" -v OFS="\t"   \
    -v city="$city"         \
    -v bedrooms="$bedrooms" \
    -v space="$space"       \
    -v price="$price"       \
    -v weeks="$weeks"       '
        $2 == city && $3 >= bedrooms && $4 >= space && $5 <= price && $6 <= weeks {
            $1 = $1; print
        }
' listing |
sort   -t $'\t' $sortby $ordering |
column -s $'\t' -t
```

(This is not an answer, just a comment that needs formatting)

The `$1=$1` bit is an awk trick to make it rewrite the current record using the Output Field Separator, a single tab. Saves you a call to `tr`